# RE-running get requests using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I use Qt 4.8.5, Visual Studio 2010. I grab some web pages in my `QObject` derived object (CGrabber instance). m_reply is a CGrabber member with a type `QNetworkReply*`. When the page is downloaded, `page_downloaded_slot()` handles it. I go to the next URL and call `run()` to download another page. Sometimes `qDebug()` shows that `m_reply` has `isRunning()` true (though I call deleteLater on). That is why downloading the next page freezes. The 1st `run()` call is made outside `page_downloaded_slot()`.

```
void CGrabber::page_downloaded_slot( QNetworkReply* reply )
{
  //pseudocode
  if (some_condition)
  {
    reply->deleteLater();
    //get the next URL 
    run();
    return;

  }  
  reply->deleteLater();
} 

void CGrabber::run()
{
 QObject::connect(m_net_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(page_downloaded_slot(QNetworkReply*)));
 //  m_reply can be running here    
 m_reply = m_net_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(/*current URL*/));
}
```

So, how should I handle m_reply and reply in order to avoid memory leaks, prevent grabber from freezing? Maybe, I should call `abort()` or 'close()' somewhere additionally. Sometimes I need to change proxy if I met proxy errors. Also if I want to call `run()` within `page_downloaded_slot()`, but reply shows error (for example, `reply->error() == QNetworkReply::ConnectionRefusedError`), do I need additional steps in `page_downloaded_slot()`? What is the link between `reply` and `m_reply`?

Comment: when does slot page_downloaded_slot invoked ? Can you add code which connects signal to slot ?

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see any reuse of QNetworkReply objects nor read access to m_reply. You assign a new QNetworkReply object to m_reply (which is a pointer), so after the assignment, m_reply has nothing to do at all with previous requests.